# awstats configuration for domain/instance

Tags: awstats

I have a three small sites running on my Apache. I have a one domain name to access them. The access is like as follows:

```
http://www.domainname.com/site1
http://www.domainname.com/site2
http://www.domainname.com/site3
```

I have configured the AWStats for Analysis of requests coming to my `www.domainname.com`. But, My requirement is to have Awstats to only track requests coming to the

`www.domainname.com/site2`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter "urldetail" for "site2"

```
perl awstats.pl -config=myconfig -output=urldetail:/site2 -staticlinks > output.html
```

Look under III.1.a) here:
http://awstats.sourceforge.net/docs/awstats_setup.html#READ

Comment: I managed to achieve this with $tri in w3perl (if it hasn't to be awstats for you)

Comment: So which one did the job for you? awstats or w3perl ?